How can I specify additional gui plugins in world.sdf file without overwriting default gui config
When I include a gui plugin that I would like to have activated by default, it overwrites the default gui config so that the plugin is the ONLY thing that is visible. I would like to be able to have this plugin activated by default (bonus if you can help me change some settings with it using the sdf file). I would also like to specify a follow target from the sdf to follow at startup (bonus if there is a way to change the follow camera parameters to make it more stiff or fixed to the rear of the vehicle regardless of direction of travel).
<gui fullscreen="false">
    <plugin filename="VisualizeLidar" name="Visualize Lidar">
    </plugin>
</gui>


Gazebo Sim API Reference references a few solutions at API Reference gui_config.

The easiest and quickest is by editing the gui.config

By default you're loading this file:
$HOME/.gz/sim/<#>/gui.config

Adding the plugin here without the <gui></gui> should add the plugin for every instance of Gazebo when not specified otherwise, or overridden by the world.sdf.

Secondly, you could copy the gui.config file to an alternative location, edit the copy and load it when starting your Gazebo world:

gz sim <path to>/fuel_preview.sdf --gui-config <path to>saved.config

I highly advise this method.
The default gui.config can be found at gz-sim/src/gui/gui.config at the gz-sim GitHub

Alternatively you could add all (useful) plugins referenced in the gui.config to your world.sdf within <gui></gui> and load your world.
